# Jenkins Started by upstream project Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: returned status code 128: stderr: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

The problem is that I have a multi-job project, called **Job-Full** which runs 4 other jobs: **Backend**, **Frontend**,**Copy_Configs**,**Deploy**.
And I decided to migrate the job Copy_Configs *(it was created in Jenkins` web-gui like other jobs, so the configuration of the job stores in config.xml)* to Copy_Configs_Pipeline via Jenkinsfile and added it to a repo. When I run only Copy_Configs_Pipeline it works properly, but when I added it in Multijob Project instead of old Copy_Configs and then run Job-Full,- all steps before Copy_Confgis_Pipeline finished successfully, but when turns come to Copy_Configs_Pipeline it fails with error from the screen
[returned status code 128:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D579G.png)
There is a screenshot that my pipeline works when runs alone
[works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldxyy.jpg)

I tried to fix like said in (https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/jenkins-with-git-client-needs-permission-on-temporary-directory) article. But it didn't help.
02.03.23
Also tried this variant https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

Answer (score 0):

**Old answer**. Like MarkEWaite (Mark Waite) did reply The message says:

cat: not found

That indicates that the PATH of the agent or controller that is running the git command does not have the cat program in its path. Something has harmed the PATH on that agent. Look to see what has modified the PATH

You're more likely to receive answers when you post the text of the failure message rather than a picture of a failure message.  The picture of the failure message doesn't allow others to copy and paste it.  The picture of the failure message requires that the reader must open the image to view it.  When extra actions are required of the reader, it reduces the likelihood of a response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyv3O.png)

**UPDATE 10.04.23**:This is the problem with nodelabel-paramter-plugin. As mentioned https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68991
And this is not fixed yet...